# Combining DrawerLayout with CoordinatorLayout and FAB

Tags: android, android-layout, drawerlayout, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

For my question I have prepared [a simple project at GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/q40/NaviFab).

In an app with `DrawerLayout` I am trying to display a login page for social networks (Google+, Facebook, Twitter).

The login page should display the social network logo (or user photo - if logged in), then horizontal progress bar and a `FloatingActionButton` and finally some text at the bottom:

[image: app screenshot]

Unfortunately, I have some strange artefact in the `ActionBar` area - as you can see in the right side of the above screenshot.

Why does it happen please and how to fix this?

Here is my [activity_main.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q40/NaviFab/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) with `DrawerLayout` and left drawer menu:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF0"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#FFF"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item_text"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item_text"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_left"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here is my [fragment_google.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q40/NaviFab/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_google.xml) with `CoordinatorLayout` and `FAB`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:src="@drawable/photo"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Main profile"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/given"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/photo"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/photo"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_plus_white_48dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `fitsSystemWindows="true"` from [fragment_google.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/NaviFab/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_google.xml) has solved the problem:

[image: app screenshot]